# condescending moderator

Tags: discussion

I'm new to electronics, and i made a schematic of something i wanted to try to build.

[I asked something and included a picture of what i meant](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/214546/charging-two-18650s-with-solar-panels-and-usb-charger), but a battery i linked apparently had too much mAh to be realistic.

Instead of correcting me and explaining that a 18650 couldn't hold that much power, i was ridiculed by someone that didn't even bother to try to answer my question.

I thought this was strange, but I didn't expect a moderator to do the same. Instead of correcting the other commenter, or helping me, he made some stupid joke about how *fire* was in the name of the battery and that my battery would catch fire because it had so much mAh.

From the "[reputation & moderation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators)" page in the help center i got this:

> (moderators) are patient and fair, lead by example and show respect for their fellow community members in their actions and words

I don't think this moderator did any of that, is that normal?

thank you

edit: you guys are right, im an idiot, i should have done more research. i won't remove the post so others dont make the same mistake

Comment: Asking a question here is expected to involve a decent amount of prior research, common sense and understanding of the basics. Neither is shown there, and we are all humans that like to make fun of stupid products, nothing of which is against the guidelines.

Comment: Please read-up: [BU-204. How do Lithium Batteries Work?](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/lithium_based_batteries), and [BU-304a. Safety Concerns with Li-ion](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/safety_concerns_with_li_ion).  If you absorb that, you should be able to understand Lithium battery humor.

Comment: Did you already buy the batteries? I'm struggling to come up with other reasons to be so emotionally attached to your battery decision. I'm also having difficulty  equating a stupid joke (so bad that it hertz) to condescension.

Comment: Note for the archive: the offending question has been moderated into oblivion and is no longer available for reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Grow up and get over it.

The sloppiness exhibited in by your question tells people you don't really care nor take this seriously, so why should they?  As a result, the volunteers that might otherwise have given their free time to help you are more likely to joke amongst themselves and move on.  That's how life works when you disrespect people.  Again, grow up and get over it.

Next time show the care in your question that you apparently expect others to spend on their answers.  You wasted your one chance to make a good first impression.

If anything, the comment by Bruce Abbott was the most direct.  It was sarcastically saying that 9.8 Ah for a 18650 cell is absurd, as even a modicum of looking at available batteries would have told you.  This demonstrates no research or effort on your part.  Bruce's comment was not out of line, and Nick's comment was even more minor.  There was nothing wrong with either.

Grow up and get over it.

Comment: Almost a perfect answer, but could use some more emphasis on the growing up, and getting over it parts.

Comment: yeah, "grow up! get over it!" what is wrong with people in this community

Comment: @gesell Let me let you in on a secret. You don't just barge into an established community, and as a newcomer, whine and complain about the way the community works. Stop it. All you're doing is pissing people off.

Comment: Thanks for trusting me with your secret. Here's another secret: There's already a community where you can treat newcomers asking polite question like trash, it's called 4chan. I had no clue this is what EE.SE was shooting for.

Answer (score -4):

I read your question and as a beginner myself I found that you tried to explain the question to the best of your ability. The problem is that some users respond in short aggressive ways. The response to your linked question and even this one here are clear examples of that happening. It would be great if one day we could block users but until then just do your best to ignore them or find other places to ask beginner questions.

Comment: Thought you were leaving?